# Is there a way to get vecfn to call on vecadd getting #<procedure:vecadd>

Tags: scheme, racket

So I want to run a definition, from my `vecfn` that calls on `vecadd`, but when it calls it goes with `#procedure:vecadd`. Also planning to do it with other procedure such as `-` and `/`.

I've tried to look up what the #procedure is but it only gave me arithmetic examples. It doesn't address the issue of why `#procedure` is popping up.

```
(define (vecfn x list1 list2)
    (if (eqv? x +)
         vecadd
    (if (eqv? x -)
         vecsub      
    (if (eqv? x /)
         vecdiv       
          '()))))

(define (vecadd list1 list2)
  (cond ((and (pair? list1) (pair? list2))
         (cons (+ (car list1) (car list2))
               (vecadd  (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))
        ((pair? list1) list1)
        (else list2)))
```

Using `(vecfn + '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))` would get me (2 4 6) but instead gave me `#procedure:vecadd`

Comment: `#<procedure:vecadd>` is just text representation of procedure `vecadd`. Your `vecfn` return a procedure, it did not call it.

Comment: Oh okay, how would I call it so I can pass the 3 parameters into the two parameters for the procedure of vecadd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually *calling* the `vecadd`, `vecsub` and `vecdiv` procedures, `vecfn` is returning the procedures themselves. Try this:

```
(define (vecfn x list1 list2)
  (if (eqv? x +)
      ; invoke procedure with two parameters
      (vecadd list1 list2)
      (if (eqv? x -)
          (vecsub list1 list2)
          (if (eqv? x /)
              (vecdiv list1 list2)
              '()))))
```

In Scheme you call a procedure by surrounding it with `()` and passing the parameters separated by spaces: `(vecadd list1 list2)`.

Comment: Does scheme just remove the first parameter when you invoke the 2? Or does it just ignore the first one?

Comment: What do you mean "ignore"? The parameters are `list1` and `list2`, obviously both are passed, why would they be removed? That wouldn't make any sense! And `vecadd` is not a parameter, that's the function you're calling.